# In the derivation of the Black-Scholes PDE, using delta hedging, how is this linked to the risk neutral valuation?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, finance-mathematics

I was reading this paper:
[http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/FoundationsFE/BlackScholes.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Emh2078/FoundationsFE/BlackScholes.pdf)

I don't understand the paragraph here:
"The most interesting feature of the Black-Scholes PDE (8) is that µ does not appear1
anywhere. Note that the
Black-Scholes PDE would also hold if we had assumed that µ = r. However, if µ = r then investors would not
demand a premium for holding the stock. Since this would generally only hold if investors were risk-neutral, this
method of derivatives pricing came to be known as risk-neutral pricing."

Answer (score 3):

It means that in the Black-Scholes framework (or more generally in a complete markets framework), since you can hedge all the risk away (by delta-hedging), you can price everything assuming that no risk premium is required, i.e. $\mu = r$.